# No Audio when booting from Windows or vice versa

Tags: dual-boot, sound, 15.10, windows-10

I have an interesting problem that I'm currently stuck on. I'm using **Ubuntu 15.10 alongside Windows 10** in a dual-boot system on a 2015 XPS 13. But every time I restart to another OS, my *audio stops working*.

To fix this issues, I shut down my computer, wait a couple of seconds, then boot again. Sometimes I need to repeat this procedure multiple times before it gets back to normal.

Any ideas what might be the cause of this problem?

Comment: Do you have dual boot or what do you mean by alongside?

Comment: Oh yes I see dual-boot is tagged. I don't get what you mean by switch because shutting down and then booting to another os is what you do to fix the problem but also the thing that causes the problem isn't it?

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear. If I simply restart to another OS, then I get the problem. If I shutdown and then boot to another OS, I don't get it. Hope that clears it up

Comment: Yes I now know what you mean. Could you try to shutdown your pc and immediately boot it and look if the problem still occurs. This should be equal to a reboot  so we will know more then.

Answer (score 0):

[It is a known bug with the I2S Audio Interface](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1413446).

For the moment there is no workaround. Just wait for the bug to be fixed (let's hope for Ubuntu 16.04).